# Game Centre Leaderboard - Can't set GKLeaderboardViewController delegate to self (CCLayer)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

The following code won't compile because of the error that results from trying to set the GKLeaderboardViewController delegate to the calling instance.

The error message is:

```
Assigning to 'id<UINavigationControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'MainMenu *'
```

where MainMenu is of type CCLayer.

If the assignment statement (leaderboard.delegate = self) is commented out, the code will compile, the leaderboard will display, but the callback will not be called when the "done" button is pressed.

This is the code:

```
- (void) showLeaderBoard {

    // Show GC leaderboard

    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboard = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];

    if (leaderboard != nil) {

        leaderboard.delegate = self;
        leaderboard.category = @"ldrbrd_ref";

        AppController *app = (AppController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [[app navController] presentViewController:leaderboard animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Incidentally, this is my header for the object declaration:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "CCGameButton.h"

#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

@interface MainMenu : CCLayer <CCGameButtonDelegate, GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate> {

}

+ (CCScene *) scene;

@end
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the `leaderboardDelegate` property rather than the `delegate` property. `leaderboardDelegate` requires a `<GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>` while `delegate` requires a `<UINavigationControllerDelegate>`, hence the error message.

Check the apple docs for `leaderboardDelegate`
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboardViewController_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKLeaderboardViewController/leaderboardDelegate

Comment: Bingo! Thanks a lot - That worked. Not sure how I missed that.